# Classifying to three classes using a single output

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, deep-learning, sentiment-analysis, lstm

I'm using LSTM for sentiment classification and I have three optional classes - negative/positive/neutral.

I wonder if there's a way to do this classification using a single output that will be in the range of -1:1 while -1 is the neutral class, 0 is the negative one and 1 is the positive class.

I know that *sigmoid* function goes from 0 to 1 and *tanh* from -1 to 1 so working with *tanh* is probably a good lead, but still does it make any sense using single output to classify to three different classes?

Comment: Take a look at https://class.coursera.org/ml-005/lecture/38

Comment: So there's no way of training a single classifier with a single output? I'll need to train three classifiers for this task, right?

Comment: if it's sentiment analysis, you would only need one regression that outputs 0-1 and split into 3 ranges 0-0.33, 0.33-0.66, 0.66-1.0

Comment: Iv'e already tried this approach but the results suck. In addition I have a neutral training set that I want to use so I'm I need an extra output. I'm trying the one vs rest method now. Thx

Comment: http://cs231n.github.io/linear-classify/ Check out this - I think that it might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Basically it's rather more useful to have three units for each class rather than one - which in the end gives you a score helpful in assigning appropriate class. The intuition behind this is the following :

1. A final unit (tanh or sigmoid) - should receive in it's input a huge negative number in case of negative class and a huge positive number in case of positive class.
2. So among units providing input too this final unit you should have neurons which are providing strong input in case of positive and negative classes.
3. Now take a look at neutral case - then there also should be units which will provide you a certain input to final unit in case to keep input near 0. This needs additional complexity of the net and can hurt a training because this units should not only recognize the neutral inputs but also make inputs from other units less significant.

So, to sum up - to have an efficient model which works with final output between -1 :1 you need to have the same units in your network as will do the job in case with three outputs. Moreover - you need to add additional complexity which will make the outputs from "positive" and "negative" units less significant in neutral case. So - that would rather hurt your training than help in anything.